# How to get product image by label in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, product-images

I have Magento 1.9.2 that comes with swatches feature.

I have product with following swatches: Color, Size

I created configurable product using configurable options and added assiciated products.

All images uploaded in main configurable product with label e.g. Black, White, Red ...

Child products do not have any product images.

I wish to get product image of selected option in cart (not the image set as Base or small or thumbnail).

Please help

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Child products need to have product images. They are the variations that are going to be in the cart.

This can be achieved through the backend of coarse but can take a lot of time. I would suggest loading the images you need via FTP using the `Bulk Image Import` profile.

Then run an export CSV of all simples and add the image path to the columns base, small, thumbnail.

After completing this make sure that in `System > Configuration > Checkout > Shopping Cart` the image to be used is the product thumbnail itself rather than the parent product.

Should work out all good, it just takes time.